# Celery beat schedule, schedule to run on load then on interval

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to figure out how to configure a periodic task in celery to be scheduled to run on load regardless of interval.

For example,

```
beat_schedule = {
    'my-task': {
        'task': 'module.my_task',
        'schedule': 60.0,
    },
}
```

will wait 60 seconds after the beat is started to run for the first time.

This is problematic for a longer interval, such as an hour, that can do work that is immediately valuable but is not needed "fresh" at shorter intervals.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961517/celery-beat-schedule-run-task-instantly-when-start-celery-beat) addresses this issue but neither of the answers are satisfactory:

1. Adding startup lag for the task to be en-queued is both undesirable performance-wise and bad for maintainability since the initial run and schedule are now separated.
2. Re-implementing the schedule within the task is bad for maintainability.

This seems to me something that should be obvious, so I am quite surprised that that SO question is all I can find on the matter. I am unable to figure this out from the docs and the celery github issues so I wonder if I am missing something obvious.

**Edit:**

There seems to be more to the story here, because after trying a different task with an hour interval, it ran immediately as the project celery is started.

If I stop and clear the queue with `celery purge -A proj -f` then start celery again, the task does not run within the heartbeat interval. This would makes sense because the worker handles the messages but beat has its own schedule record `celerybeat-schedule` which would be unaffected by the purge.

If I delete `celerybeat-schedule` and restart beat the task still does not run. Starting celery beat with a non-default schedule db location also does not cause the task to run. The next time the task runs is one hour from the time I started the new beat (14:59) *not* one hour from the first start time of the task (13:47).

There seems to be some state that is not documented well or is unknown that is the basis of this issue. My question can also be stated as: **how do you force beat to clear its record of last runs?**.

I am also concerned that while running the worker and beat, running `celery -A proj inspect scheduled` gives `- empty -` but presumably the task had to be scheduled at some point because it gets run.

Comment: @Jmilis Have you got any workaround yet?

Comment: @M.A.K.Simanto I never found a proper solution to this particular problem. An issue I opened on the project GH indicates it _may_ be fixed: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3854. I don't have a current use for celery so haven't checked.