# Running Django celery on load

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

Hi I am working on a project where i need celery beat to run long term periodic tasks. But the problem is that after starting the celery beat it is taking the specified time to run for the first time.

I want to fire the task on load for the first time and then run periodically.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322486/celery-beat-schedule-schedule-to-run-on-load-then-on-interval) on stackoverflow and [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3988) issue on GitHub, but didn't found a reliable solution.

Any suggestions on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this does not seem possible I suggest a different approach. Call the task explicitly when you need and let the scheduler continue scheduling the tasks as usual. You can call the task on startup by using one the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only) methods (you probably need to take care of the multiple calls of the `ready` method if the task is not idempotent). Alternatively call the task from the command line by using `celery call` after your django server startup command.