# Sending a chain tasks will run out of order when I want to send task to startup of a worker

Tags: python, celery

I want to send a chain task at startup o worker like in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14589445/3922534 question, but task run out of order.

Logs from worker

```
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,369: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.add_newspapers[5de1f446-65af-472a-a4b6-d9752142b588] received
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,372: WARNING/MainProcess] Now Runing Newspaper Function
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,408: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.check_tasks_are_created[33d6b9d1-660b-4a80-a726-6f167e246480] received
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,412: WARNING/MainProcess] Now Runing Podcast Function
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,427: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.add_newspapers[5de1f446-65af-472a-a4b6-d9752142b588] succeeded in 0.0470000000204891s: 'Now Runing Podcast Function'
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,432: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.add_yt_channels[26179491-2632-46bd-95c1-9e9dbb9e8130] received
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,433: WARNING/MainProcess] None
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,457: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.check_tasks_are_created[33d6b9d1-660b-4a80-a726-6f167e246480] succeeded in 0.0470000000204891s: None
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,463: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.add_podcasts[ad94a119-c6b2-475a-807b-b1a73bef589e] received
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,468: WARNING/MainProcess] Now Runing Check Tasks are Created Function
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,501: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.add_yt_channels[26179491-2632-46bd-95c1-9e9dbb9e8130] succeeded in 0.06299999984912574s: 'Now Runing Check Tasks are Created Function'
[2022-07-12 20:51:47,504: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.add_podcasts[ad94a119-c6b2-475a-807b-b1a73bef589e] succeeded in 0.030999999959021807s: 'Now Runing Yotube Channels Function'
```

Code How i send the task:

```
@worker_ready.connect
def at_start(sender, **k):
    with sender.app.connection() as conn:
        #sender.app.send_task(name='task.print_word', args=["I Send Task On Startup"],connection=conn,)
        #ch = [add_newspapers.s(),add_podcasts.s(),add_yt_channels.s(),check_tasks_are_created.s()]
        ch = [
            signature("task.add_podcasts"),
            signature("task.add_yt_channels"),
            signature("task.check_tasks_are_created"),
        ]
        sender.app.send_task(name='task.add_newspapers',chain=ch,connection=conn,)
```

Then I try it to run chain task like normally run apply_async(), but it runs at every worker. I want to run just once at one worker

```
@worker_ready.connect
def at_start(sender, **k):
    chain(add_newspapers.s(),add_podcasts.s(),add_yt_channels.s(),check_tasks_are_created.s()).apply_async()
```

Then I try it to recognize the worker then apply .apply_async(), but it does not catch the if statment.

Documentation https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#celeryd-init

celery -A celery_app.celery worker --loglevel=INFO -P gevent --concurrency=40 -n celeryworker1

```
@worker_ready.connect
def at_start(sender, **k):
        print("This is host name ", sender.hostname)
        if sender == "celery@celeryworker1":
            with sender.app.connection() as conn:
                chain(add_newspapers.s(),add_podcasts.s(),add_yt_channels.s(),check_tasks_are_created.s()).apply_async()
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just a bug?

Comment: `chain` promise you the order: `add_podcasts` won't start before `add_newspapers` end and so on. It doesn't promise on which worker each one of them runs. Do you expect them to run on the same worker? (that's a different issue)

Comment: yes but, when i run with with app.send_task they run out of order,even in one worker

Comment: one question why , at my 3d code sample, do u have any idea why it does note catch the if statment, i did same as in the docunation ?

Comment: because `sender` is an object and you're comparing it to `str`

Comment: how u supose to do it then ? any idea

Comment: `if sender.hostname == "celeryworker1":` is enough?

Comment: i postet the log so u can see they run out order

Comment: do you need the return value of each task for the one that comes after? (as an input)

Comment: i try it wont work,i dont know why but hostanme is empty by me

Comment: not really i dont need return at all, but i dont know how chain works with out return value,i just need to run task one after another without return

Answer (score 0):

Since a task doesn't need the return value of the previous task you can run it as:

```
chain(add_newspapers.si(),add_podcasts.si(),add_yt_channels.si(),check_tasks_are_created.si()).apply_async()
```

(change call from `s()` to `si()`

You can read about immutability [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#immutability).

Answer (score 0):

@worker_ready.connect handler will run ***on every worker***. So, if you have 10 workers, you will send the same task 10 times, when they broadcast the "worker_ready" signal. Is this intentional?